# CMake - Defining Include Paths and Library in Top-Level CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

My source tree looks like this:

```
--- src/CMakeLists.txt
--- src/MoonLanding/
----- CMakeLists.txt
----- main.cpp
```

To build the `MoonLanding` project, in `src/Moonlanding/`, I do the following

```
cmake . -DGFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/gflags/build/include \
  -DGFLAGS_LIBRARY=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/gflags/build/lib/libgflags.a \
  -DAtlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/include \
  -DAtlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/libcblas.a \
  -DAtlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/include \
  -DAtlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/liblapack.a \
  -DAtlas_BLAS_LIBRARY=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/libatlas.a \
  -DLMDB_INCLUDE_DIR=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/mdb/libraries/liblmdb \
  -DLMDB_LIBRARIES=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/mdb/libraries/liblmdb/liblmdb.so \
  -DBOOST_ROOT=${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/boost_1_56_0/
```

The above invocation to cmake works great and `MoonLanding` compiles.

However, I want to invoke `cmake .` under `src/`. To do so, I defined `src/CMakeLists.txt` as so:

```
set(GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/gflags/build/include)
set(GFLAGS_LIBRARY $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/gflags/build/lib/libgflags.a)
set(Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/include)
set(Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/libcblas.a)
set(Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/include)
set(Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/liblapack.a)
set(Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/ATLAS-install/lib/libatlas.a)
set(LMDB_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/mdb/libraries/liblmdb)
set(LMDB_LIBRARIES $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/mdb/libraries/liblmdb/liblmdb.so)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/boost_1_56_0/)

add_subdirectory(Moonlanding)
```

CMake then gives me the error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find LMDB (missing: LMDB_INCLUDE_DIR LMDB_LIBRARIES)
```

If I invoke `cmake` again, the error goes away. Overall, I need to call `cmake .` three times for `src/Moonlanding` to compile from `src/`. Why is this so and is there a cleaner way of achieving of building this project?

(The reason why I want to separate GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR and other directives is to help automate the build process for the user.)

Comment: Quite easy. After the first call variables LMDB_INCLUDE_DIR and LMDB_LIBRARIES are cached and you will not see the error. Also please check the CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log in your build root.

Comment: Why do you have `$ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}` when calling `set`, but just `${CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}` when using `-D` on the command line?

Comment: @Fraser $ENV is a CMake command to grab a system variable and for the command line that is how you dereference a system variable under Linux.

Comment: Does CBVR_DEPENDENCIES expand to an absolute or relative path?

Comment: Please show the content of `MoonLanding/CmakeLists.txt` and of the `FindLMDB.cmake` module you are using as this is not part of the CMake distribution

Comment: `cmake .` do not do like that, always use out-of-source build.

Comment: could not you just create a simple shell script, that a) builds whatever parts (libraries) the final executables share (using a separate cmake invocation for each), and b) builds the depending executables (again, with N cmake runs)?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference (applicable for your case) between setting variable from command line and cmake `set()` command is default caching strategy.

Most likely you can solve your problem by caching the values:

```
set(GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR $ENV{CBVR_DEPENDENCIES}/gflags/build/include CACHE PATH "Some comment here")
# other sets with "CACHE" addition
```

PS. don't forget to make a clean build after each caching-related change in cmake sources

Comment: +1 Don't answer all Stackoverflow questions by yourself. Leave some for us!